# Is this use of JavaScript eval admissible?

Tags: javascript, ajax, eval

I am making a website and I want to use the following design:
Each time a user clicks a link an ajax request is sent.
The reply contains 2 fields:

- the HTML that replaces the content area
- A JavaScript to be evaluated (JavaScript behaviors attached to objects withing the new HTML content)

Does this use of JavaScript eval() have any downsides?

#### Edit

The JavaScript that is to be evaluated is varied - it's not something that can be sensibly expressed with a single function taking different arguments.
Cross-site scripting was mentioned, but I don't see how this use is different from a user visiting a new JavaScript-containing page.

Comment: This really depends on exactly what Javascript is going to be returned from the server. If what it returns is fairly consistent, there's almost certainly a better way. If what it returns isn't consistent at all, there may still be a better way. Please post a little more detail.

Comment: Have you considered loading the JavaScript code with the initial web-page?

Comment: All the "big" functions are in an external .js loaded on first entrance. The to-be-evaled scripts attach behaviours to newly created elements

Comment: @sabof Attaching behaviors to dynamic elements is done via event delegation. This enables you to attach all behaviors on page-load, and it will still work on all the elements that were added subsequently.

Comment: This needs some goggling, but sounds like something that might make things simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mainly depends upon how the javascript to be evaluated is generated.  Any use of eval is potentially subject to cross site scripting, but only if the js is generated by something that a user can control.  If the server is returning a static js, that's no more inherently bad than the use of js anywhere else.

Comment: In this case the JavaScript is not affected by user input in any way. But if someone can't add JavaScript to newly generated pages presented to a different user, is cross site scripting something I still need to worry about?

Comment: @sabof: No, you don't have to worry about xss attacks if the javascript is never presented to a different user. But as always you need to validate any user input server side, and you've just provided them with an easy way to change the input client side.  Not really an additional risk, except insofar as the client may have bugs in their code that is going to be evaluated, bugs which can affect what is submitted to the server.

Comment: Note that this is exactly what sites like jsFiddle are doing, except that they are even allowing it to be presented to other users.  Of course they don't run the code automatically...

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of any, although my imagination may be a bit lacking. ) Besides, isn't JSONP something of the same method?

Comment: I have seen several "eval considered harmful" type articles, at the same time to me it seems like the simplest method to accomplish what I am doing. After all isn't that what browsers do?